# How do I update MySQL table, using subselect

Tags: mysql

how can i write the query, to update the table `videos`, and set the value of field `name` to 'something' where the `average` is max(), or UPDATE the table, where `average` has the second value by size!!!

i think the query must look like this!!!

```
UPDATE videos 
   SET name = 'something' 
 WHERE average IN (SELECT `average`
                     FROM `videos`
                 ORDER BY `average` DESC
                    LIMIT 1)
```

but it doesn't work!!!

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450587/mysql-update-where-some-field-is-max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things here cause problems with my version of mysql (5.0.84)
1.  Using limit not supported in subquery
2.  Using table for update (videos) in subquery

I can't think of a good way to get around these problems.  I'd suggest pulling the ids of hte rows you want to update out into your code and then executing the update in a second statement.  If you are using pure sql and doing this by hand then you could always just select into a temp table and then update based on the ids that you insert there.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE videos 
   SET name = 'something' 
 WHERE videos.id IN (SELECT id
                     FROM `videos`
                 ORDER BY `average` DESC
                    LIMIT 1)
```